# What is the difference between 'take a look' at and 'look at'?

Tags: meaning

There are two sentences below:

1. The policeman looked at the boy.
2. He took a look at me.

What is the difference between 'take a look' at and 'look at'in meaning?

Answer (score 3):

No, they are different!

[*take a look* is an idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+a+look+at) which means *"to observe or examine someone or something."*

On the other hand, *looking at someone* is merely an act of seeing someone. The *purpose* of the former one is different.

You look at some product as a normal physiological gesture but if you 'take a look' at the same product, you have a purpose to study/observe it.

Comment: +1. My car's been acting up, so I'm going to have the mechanic take a look at it.

Comment: Considering the fact that this question is exactly the same question asked on ES, Can this post be a duplicate? see here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22827/have-a-look-vs-take-a-look

Comment: @TRomano I hope you didn't mean to say that *I asked the mechanic to look at my car* doesn't mean *I asked the mechanic to take/have a look at my car*!

Comment: @Damkerng T.  No, I was simply corroborating Maulik's answer about "study and observation", giving a typical scenario where the phrase is used, and a sentence that helps to show its informal register.

Comment: @TRomano *Phew!* -- Maybe I was wrong, but when I read this answer, I saw "No, they are different!" and then "On the other hand, looking at someone is merely an act of seeing someone. The purpose of the former one is different.", and then I saw your +1, so I thought you might've been thinking that way.

Comment: The mechanic could say, "Park your car in the lot tonight, and drop your keys through the after-hours slot.  I will {take a look at it|look at it} tomorrow."  While "look at" can mean either  "direct one's gaze towards" or "examine in a brief or cursory manner", "take a look at" never means simply "direct one's gaze towards". It always means "to examine, to size up or assess". If you take your car to the mechanic because it's making a noise and ask him "to take a look at it", you don't expect a bill for $1500. You want a quick opinion of what might be wrong, not a full-blown investigation.

Comment: @TRomano I have a mixed feeling, reading your comment. I'm sure that you know when you'd use *take a look at* and when you'd use *look at*, but that's because you know it. For someone who doesn't, such as the OP who is a learner, this answer and your generalization in the last comment could be misleading. Then again, this matter is not that trivial that we can simply say, "yes, they're the same" or "no, they're different". Counterexamples are commonplace (but we could go into arguing what are "look", "examine", and "inspect"), e.g. `"Take a look at this *"` or `"Did you look at her when/as *"`

Comment: @Damkerng T. I don't see what is misleading about my mechanic example. Care to elaborate how it misleads? Care to give me a counterexample, where "take a look at" simply means "turn one's gaze towards" with no implication of "briefly examine" or "quick, cursory perusal"?  Looking and examining are quite different. There's no splitting of hairs there.

Comment: @TRomano That's what I meant by 'we could go into arguing what are "look", "examine", and "inspect"' (or as said in this answer, "study/observe"). How can we turn our gaze towards something without looking at it, or in your choice of words to discern this difference, without taking a look at it? And how brief is briefly? I don't think it's that cut and dried, and by decisively saying that there are only two shades of grey as this answer (or perhaps three or four shades as in your comments), it's misleading for the learners, IMHO. (For a longer discussion, chat rooms are better, I believe.)